Adding animation length to script
So I got a script from this link and it works perfectly, I would just like to make the animation slower. I'm not a javascript or jquery person, so help would be appreciated.
For reference here's the script.
<script>
var aDiv = document.getElementById("navi");

function changeWidth() 
{
    var scrollVal = window.pageYOffset;
    var scrollSlow  = (scrollVal / 3);
    
    //Changing CSS Width
    aDiv.style.width = Math.min(Math.max(scrollSlow, 20), 100) + "%";
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() 
{
    requestAnimationFrame(changeWidth);
}, false);
</script>

I haven't tried much on this, because I don't know scripting very well.

Are you sure there's no associated CSS transition for this? As it stands, there is no animation in your question

Do I add that via css or javascript?

I figured it out. Your question helped me understand what was going on. Thank you so much!

You should add your solution as an answer below

What do you mean by "slower"? The duration of the actual animation or the amount of required pixels that the user scrolls to get 100% of your #nav element. If the latter, then change the divisor in scrollVal / 3 to a higher number.

You can nowadays use scroll-driven CSS animation, and here's an example by Kevin Powell.

So adding a transition to the div in the css seems to have done what I wanted. It didn't do it entirely correctly, but enough to where I feel comfortable with the transition.
The css
#navi { 
z-index: 999999;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
min-width: 95%;
height: 20px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 15px;
    background: var(--gradient), var(--bg-img);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border-bottom: 0.5px solid var(--accent);
transition: 1s ease;

}
And the script, which stayed mostly the same.
<script>
var aDiv = document.getElementById("navi");

function changeWidth() 
{
var scrollVal = window.pageYOffset;
var scrollSlow  = (scrollVal / 1);

//Changing CSS Width
aDiv.style.width = Math.min(Math.max(scrollSlow, 20), 100) + "%";
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() 
{
requestAnimationFrame(changeWidth);
}, false);
</script>

This created a slower transition, though as I scrolled down, it didn't take effect until I stopped scrolling.
